# how to make a button where the image is in a span

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have this in html

```
<form id="contact-form" action="#0" class="ae-form--full">
            <input type="text" placeholder="* Name" required>
            <input type="email" placeholder="* Email" required>
            <textarea placeholder="Message ..." cols="30" rows="4"></textarea>
            <p class="au-xs-ta-right au-pt-4 group-buttons"><a href="#0" class="arrow-button arrow-button--right arrow-button--out">Send<span class="arrow-cont">
                  <svg>
                    <use xlink:href="assets/img/symbols.svg#arrow"></use>
                  </svg></span></a></p>
          </form>
```

Now I wonder how I can make the submit button with the classes and where a svg image must be placed in a span.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is you should be using the rails form helper like [form_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html)
I like to use [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)

still what you are looking should look something like this.

```
<%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>:
  <%= f.text_field :name %><br />

  <%= f.label :email %>:
  <%= f.text_field :email %><br />

  <%= f.label :message %>:
  <%= f.text_area(:message, cols: 20, rows: 40) %><br />
    <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-primary") do %>
      Save <span class="icon-ok icon-white"></span> 
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

try making your btn like

```
<%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-primary") do %>
  Save <span class="icon-ok icon-white"></span> 
<% end %>
```

---

Simple_form example

```
<%= simple_form_for @contact do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.input :message %>
  <span>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </span>
<% end %>
```

I am not sure if you know that in the controller you should have:

```
def new 
  @contact = Contact.new
end
```

I hope that this helps

Comment: oke, but I think I loose the post part or do I miss something and I miss the svg image.

Comment: you want to submit the form?

Comment: yes, I want to do that. Here is the example that I try to use : http://themes-pixeden.com/landing/urku/contact.html

Comment: let me know if this helps

Comment: I use a simple form. I see now a button where I want to see a link and I miss the svg image after the button

Comment: if you are using simple_form you should post the simple_form code and not the rendered HTML

Comment: oke, here what I have now :  https://gist.github.com/rwobben/ec0fe87879cd01e7ac9dc16a846a5592. I see then this error message : SyntaxError (/home/ubuntu/workspace/ticketee/app/views/projects/_form.html.erb:21: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end

Comment: the form is working : see the same gists. the only problem is that I see Save and the arrow under each other instead of next to each other. See https://ticketee-wissel.c9users.io/projects/new. I think I need to change the css from a to a button one. Sorry, I cannot skype. It here 10 o' clock in the evening and time for me to sleep

Comment: I just updates the BTN code let me know if that worked for you

Comment: if I understand you well I had to do  ` Save <span class="arrow-cont"><%= inline_svg ('arrow.svg') %></span>`  but no luck

Comment: almost no difference. See the page I was telling you, where you can see what happens. I think I have to fiddle with the css

Answer (score 1):

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="get_drug_search_results">
   <span class="textm"><%= t("labels.find_result") %></span>
   <span class="icon "><%=image_tag("magnifying-glass-grey.png", width: 20, height: 20,:id=> "image")%></span>
</button>
```